# Erlang: Sorting arrays

Tags: erlang

I am new with functional programming languages and I can't understand why in Erlang, if I take a BubbleSort, QuickSort or any other sorting algorithms and try to sort [8] it will return "\b". Or [12,10,11] will return "\n\v\f". Can someone  please help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to the fact that Erlang represents strings as lists of numbers. When printing such a list, the Erlang output function will look to see whether your list contains all numbers that correspond to ASCII character values. If so, then it prints your list as a string.

It sounds like your code is working correctly. Try sorting `[12345, 29348, 978]` with your existing code to see what happens.

See the [reference manual section 2.11 String](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id73373) for information about this.

Comment: It returned "[978,12345,29348]".

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

It's because they mean the same thing: 8 in ASCII is "\b". See the "lists!" section [here](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real).

> Erlang will print lists of numbers as numbers only when at least one
>   of them could not also represent a letter!

So the erlang shell is trying to help you out by making its best guess about what you want to see. Occasionally, you get a string when you meant to see a list of integers which can be confusing. The following illustrates this point:

```
1> [104, 101, 108, 108, 111].
"hello"
2> [104, 101, 108, 108, 111, -1].
[104,101,108,108,111,-1]
3> [104, 101, 108, 108, 111] =:= "hello".
true
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for this is because Erlang basically takes these as the corresponding ASCII values for the characters which are being printed.
I would like to post a piece of code which sorts in erlang:

```
    -module(solution).
    -import(lists,[delete/2,max/1]).
    -compile(export_all).
    selection_sort([],Sort)-> Sort;
    selection_sort(Ar,Sort)->
        M=max(Ar),
        Ad=delete(M,Ar),
        selection_sort(Ad,[M|Sort]).
    print_array([])->ok;
    print_array([H|T])->
        io:format("~p~n",[H]),
        print_array(T). 

   main()->
        Ans=selection_sort([1,5,7,8,4,10],[]),
        print_array(Ans).
```

Hope THE Above code can solve your problem